# sudo password for terminal

Tags: sudo

I'm quite  new to Linux. I am currently using Ubuntu on my HP Celeron laptop.
I've been having trouble with my  wifi on my laptop. I've tried pressing the button to activate my wifi but it doesn't seem to be responding.
So, I'm trying to run this troubleshooting command:

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

But when i try AND PRESS enter, it asks for a sudo password. First of all, What is it? Secondly,  Where do I get it? I'd really appreciate some help. I need to get back on  the network at work asap.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sudo is for users that have been put on the Sudoers list; in other words, users that have been granted limited administration rights. This allows people to modify otherwise restricted things, without direct root access, and allows for effective logging of such actions.

The sudo password is your password. For example,

```
[sudo] password for bowser:
```

I would then type my password.

Answer (score 1):

The default sudo password for your installation (I am assuming you are a new user) is the password you set for yourself, when you set up Ubuntu.  By default, you are a member of the sudoers list, and the system is asking you to verify who you are.